# Developer tools in IE7 to view console log messages

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

In IE 8 I saw a developer tools section and was able to get to its javascript console and see the console logs I was writing in it... but I can't find such a thing in IE 7 ? Where is it ? does it have it ? I just want to see the output of my console log commands in IE 7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The developer tools were added to Internet Explorer in version 8, unfortunately they are not available in IE7 natively, however they can be added with an [additional download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).  According to the documentation, this add-on does not provide additional Javascript Debugging capabilities.  You can look into Firebug Lite for IE7, however it will not be as robust as Firebug or Developer Tools, but it does provide a rudimentary console for logging script output.

To view the features/missing features of Firebug Lite [visit this page](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#WhatsNot).

Comment: IE 7 has Developer Toolbar - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Ian beat me to it; but I don't believe it included a console so you will probably have to use Firebug Lite for that.

Comment: @UselessCode That's what I thought, but I swear when I used it recently, it was under the "Scripts" (or whatever) tab. After trying a million things to use a console in the Developer Toolbar, it was in the last place I thought. I don't remember, I'll try and run it and see

Comment: @Ian All of the `features` seem to be in reference to HTML & CSS.  The best bet is probably not to support IE7 :)

Comment: @KevinBowersox : Ok I wanted to use FireBug, there was a script link in their website that I added to my code to reference it, now how do I activate it?

Comment: You should be able to add this script at the top of your page `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>` Then try F12

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yeah, I'm just wrong about Developer Toolbar. I must be thinking of something else I've used, that had a hidden console. I don't know, weird. Anyways, I wish IE 7 didn't need supported anymore. I always thought Firebug Lite was the best option for IE 7, I just thought Developer Toolbar was an alternative for a console, but I was wrong :)

Comment: @user1899082 Or bookmark the bookmarklet and run that - it'll put it on your page

Answer (score 3):

IE 7 has the Developer Toolbar, which doesn't have as many features/support as Developer Tools. Here's a reference to the add-on:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: oh I didn't know that. Ok instlled it but still can't find a menu option or something to activate and view it...

Comment: @user1899082 My fault, I was mistaken and forgot that the Developer Toolbar doesn't include a console. I'd definitely recomment Firebug Lite

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

The links in these above answers are both invalid links, Firebug Lite seems can not be installed on my Window Vista, IE7, finally, the following works for me:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/Installing

It provides a console for IE6 or IE7, so you can see what are the error (in the console log)

- Screenshot

[image]