# Tree with JavaScript not working properly on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I need some help with my JavaScript, as it behaves strangely while I am testing on Internet Explorer 7, but it works fine on Internet Explorer 8,Google Chrome,and firefox. the problem is that when ever i click on the extreme left of P1, P2, Cello, C2, C1 withen the green shaded region, my tree collapse back to Item which should not happen. It should be somewhat like that if i click on parker or cell or item, its sub-parts will be closed or open.

---

```
 var Objectkeys = function(obj){
        a = []
        for(var prop in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             a.push(prop);
            }
        };
        return a;
    },
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li,span;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if ((e.target || e.srcElement).tagName !== "LI") return;
                var classNames = this.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    this.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                if (!e)
                    e = window.event;
                    if (e.stopPropagation) {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                else {
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                }
            }
            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Objectkeys(obj[prop]).length) {

                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    },
    sortedObject = function (obj) {
        document.getElementById("dvList2").innerHTML = "";
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li,keys = Objectkeys(obj).sort();
        for (prop in keys) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[prop]));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if ((e.target || e.srcElement).tagName !== "LI") return;
                var classNames = this.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    this.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                if (!e)
                    e = window.event;
                    if (e.stopPropagation) {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                else {
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                }
            }
            if (typeof obj[keys[prop]] == "object" && Objectkeys(obj[keys[prop]]).length) {
                li.appendChild(sortedObject(obj[keys[prop]]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
    document.getElementById("hlGSL").onclick = function(){document.getElementById("dvList2").appendChild(sortedObject(dataSource));}
}
```

---

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/105/)

Comment: Click the "JSHint" button in jsfiddle. I would start fixing all of those warnings first.

Comment: Sir , its done, now please help me with the problem

Comment: Fiddle still the same... but I don't have IE7, I'd look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112345/developer-tools-in-ie7-to-view-console-log-messages, and try debuggin the code, or use jQuery

Comment: I dont want to use jquery, you can go to ie and press f12 and change to ie 7 mode...and test

Comment: Emulation mode is not the exactly the same, have you tried actual IE7 browser? What error do you get in console? Did you trace the stack? Where did it stop working?

Comment: okay give me a min i will downgrade my browser

Comment: You forgot to declare a variable, and another one is duplicated. Old IEs are very picky, even an extra comma can trigger an error, that's what I suggest you fix all of those JSHint warnings first, it might work by just doing that.

Comment: Also jsFiddle might not even work in IE7.

Comment: i am confused that what should i do...

Comment: i checked same problem with ie 7

Comment: TBH if after fixing all those warnings it doesn't work I would just use jQuery. It's ~40k gzip, no big deal, and will save you countless hours, specially with old IEs.

Comment: Lets see if someone else give me a better tips, so that i can remove this bug

Comment: By the way sir, do you fine any wrong with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript works fine, even in IE7 (tested using emulation mode in IE11).

The different behaviour you're seeing is because IE7 and below use `margin` to indent `ul` elements while all other browsers use `padding`. Add following CSS to normalize that:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

You can use the DOM Explorer's element selection tool (hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open) to see what element you're actually clicking on in order to fix such issues much faster.